# Confusion with C++20 concepts: constructible_from constraint on member type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

(Question arises from toying with concepts; don't take this to be a consequential engineering choice or anything.)

I'm trying to specify that a type satisfying a concept must have a member type, and that member type must be constructible in a certain way. As a minimal example, it must be constructible from 3 integers. But I can't figure out how to express this correctly:

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T> concept Foo = requires {
  typename T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers;
  std::constructible_from<typename T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers, int, int, int>;
  // I originally wrote
  // std::constructible_from<T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers, int, int, int>;
  // but compiler (clang++-12) gave an error and suggested the typename keyword
};

struct ThreeIntegers {
  int x, y, z;
};

struct SatisfiesFoo {
  using TypeLikeThreeIntegers = ThreeIntegers;
};

static_assert(Foo<SatisfiesFoo>);
// all is good so far

struct OnlyTwoIntegers {
  int x, y;
};

struct ShouldNotSatisfyFoo {
  using TypeLikeThreeIntegers = OnlyTwoIntegers;
};

static_assert(Foo<ShouldNotSatisfyFoo>);
// I expect this to fail but it doesn't!

int main() {
  SatisfiesFoo::TypeLikeThreeIntegers v1{1, 2, 3};
  // ShouldNotSatisfyFoo::TypeLikeThreeIntegers v2{1, 2, 3}; (error)
  // would like the concept Foo to prevent such an error and give useful diagnostic
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::constructible_from` in your `requires` clause will only check the **validity** of `std::constructible_from` and will not evaluate it, you should use extra `requires` to check:

```
template <typename T> concept Foo = requires {
  typename T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers;
  requires std::constructible_from<typename T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers, int, int, int>;
};
```

But this should sufficient:

```
template <typename T> concept Foo = 
  std::constructible_from<typename T::TypeLikeThreeIntegers, int, int, int>;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xdG6h917q)

Please note that Clang will [still fail](https://godbolt.org/z/bzzM7f1qa) because it does not implement [P0960R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html), so currently `is_constructible` does not work for aggregates:

```
struct S { int x; };
static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<S, int>); // fails only on Clang
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really clarified the difference between simple requirements and nested requirements to me.